# Difficulty showing japanese characters with java substance

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization, look-and-feel

For some reason, when I have japanese characters in the title bar that is themed with java substance, I am not able to display them.  Instead it shows as squares.  If I have no substance theme, I can see the japanese characters in the title bar just fine.  I have found ways to show these characters in all other parts of my program except for the title bar.  How do I do it for this?

Comment: Please edit, don't repost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936123/showing-japanese-characters-in-title-bar-of-java-program

Answer (score 0):

The title bar needs to be in a font which supports Japanese characters. This is usually controlled by the window manager such as the one built in to MS Windows.

Can you display Japanese characters in the title bar of other programs?

Comment: Yes I am able to with using a title on a regular JLabel.  The issue is when you factor in java substance.  Java substance overrides what you have for the title bar font for Windows XP.  It overrides it to a font that is not able to display the japanese characters.

Comment: In that case can you override the code which is overriding the font?

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to.  I do not know a way to do this, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but try setting this [property](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)) before you draw your first JFrame:

JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false)